# Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am using requests python library to access an internal api -

`x1 = requests.post(url, json = data, headers = headers)`

But got this error message -
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: '' (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

I tried some of the other answer, but the issue is still there.
How to resolve the issue. What is the reason for the issue, as previously it was working fine.

Comment: Looks like you are using a self signed cert. try `x1 = requests.post(url, json = data, headers = headers, verify=False) `

Comment: @BijayRegmi Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] to list up and describe _exactly_ the solutions you've tried? Otherwise, people would just say answers that you already tried and/or close this as a duplicate of the many, _many_, other questions about `SSLCertVerificationError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution later.
I just edited the host entry in the server for the url to make the post request.

You can edit your host file at server/system -

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

There I added, eg -

```
IP Url
0.0.0.0 google.com 
1.1.1.1 abc.com
```

This solves my error.

Comment: and set verify=False
like that
rec = requests.post(url, json = data, headers = headers,verify=False)

Comment: @danny how to add certificates into venv? Its failing for me to all https requests.